# Bash run two commands both dependent on the first

Tags: bash

I'm sure this has been asked but my search has been fruitless.

I want to run 3 bash commands in order with both the second and third only running if the first succeeded.

Example:

```
## Setup
mkdir so_test_tmp && cd so_test_tmp
echo "This is something" > something
cd ..

## Example commands
cd so_test_tmp ??? cat nothing ??? cd ..    # 0.
cd so_test_tmp ??? cat something ??? cd ..  # 1.
cd does_not_exist ??? cat nothing ??? cd .. # 2.
```

These three commands should always end in PWD. In `0.` the first cd is run, then the last. In `1.` all three commands successfully run. In `2.` the first command fails so the second and third are not run.

Comment: `I want to run 3 bash commands` Which commands? `These three commands ` Which does "these" refer to? `In 0. the first cd is run, then the last` the "last" cd? The `cd ..`? `In 1.` What does "in 1." mean? Are these some cases?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes you're right this is a good comment. I was looking for the general case because that would be most useful. Perhaps my specific usage should also be posted but I believe that is now a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Specifically for `cd somewhere && somecommand && cd ..`

The `cd ..` is only necessary because you're doing `cd so_test_tmp` inside your parent shell, as opposed to the subshell that's `fork()`ed off to then be replaced with a copy of `/bin/cat`.

By creating an explicit subshell with `( ... )`, you can scope the `cd` to its contents. By using `exec` for the last command in the subshell, you can consume it, balancing out the performance overhead of that subshell's creation.

```
(cd so_test_tmp && exec cat nothing)    # 0.
(cd so_test_tmp && exec cat something)  # 1.
(cd does_not_exist && exec cat nothing) # 2.
```

Note that this applies only when the command you're running in a subdirectory doesn't change the state of the shell that started it (like setting a variable). If you need to set a variable, you might instead want something like `output=$(cd /to/directory && exec some_command)`.

---

#### Answering the more general question

Use `&&` to connect the first command to a group with the second and third commands, and use `;` to combine those 2nd and 3rd commands, if your goal is to ensure that both 2nd and 3rd run if-and-only-if the 1st succeeds.

```
cd so_test_tmp && { cat nothing; cd ..; }    # 0.
cd so_test_tmp && { cat something; cd ..; }  # 1.
cd does_not_exist && { cat nothing; cd ..; } # 2.
```

Comment: BTW, just to be clear, `cd so_test_tmp && { cat nothing; cd ..; }` is not usage that I recommend. What if the `cd ..` fails for some reason? Even if it's something silly (a transient NFS error), that could leave the rest of your script making changes in the wrong directory.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with it? If it fails, then a `&&` chain following won't be executed.

Comment: @user2183336, I'm talking about the `cd ..` -- at the end of the chain -- failing, not the `cd so_test_tmp` at the front of the chain. There's no `&&` after the `cd ..`

Comment: @user2183336, ...to be sure, it would be _unusual_ for that to fail, but "unusual" is not "impossible". There's a reason http://shellcheck.net/ warns whenever it finds a `cd` operation that doesn't have its exit status checked, even if that's as simple as `cd .. || exit` to abort the script in presence of a failure.

Answer (score 4):

What about?

```
pushd .; cmd1 && cmd2 && ... cmdn; popd
```

- `pushd .` saves your current dir.
- Then you execute your commands; you use `&&` so that, if one fails, the others are not executed.
- `popd` goes back to your initial dir.

**EDIT**: regarding your comment below, yes, this `pushd .; popd` construct is quite silly; it lets you forget about how the execution of each set of commands went.

```
pushd .; cd so_test_tmp && cat nothing; popd; # 0.
pushd .; cd so_test_tmp && cat something; popd; # 1.
pushd .; cd does_not_exist && cat nothing; popd; # 2.
```

- You finish at your original dir after running the three sets of commands.
- Within each set of commands, whenever a command fails, it shortcuts the execution of the others behind (see they are separated by `&&`).

If you need to know if each set of commands succeeded or not, you can always test the result of the execution (and go to your initial dir and save it again before running the following set of commands):

```
pushd .;
cd so_test_tmp && cat nothing && cd .. ; # 0.
test $? -eq 0 || (popd; pushd .) ;
cd so_test_tmp && cat something && cd ..; # 1.
test $? -eq 0 || (popd; pushd .) ;
cd does_not_exist && cat nothing && cd ..; # 2.
test $? -eq 0 || (popd; pushd .) ;
```

Comment: my only problem with this is you can't chain these because the pushd/popd outer wrapper is always successful. So if your inner commands fail, then you don't know and can't be dependent on that.

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` are interactive extensions. Shells compiled for only scripted use may not include them. Much better to use `cd /path || exit`, or `(cd /to/dir && exec somecommand)` to run only `somecommand` inside `/to/dir`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! That last solution looks much more beautiful and correct than mine!

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir so_test_tmp
$ echo "This is something" > so_test_tmp/something
```

Wrapping an `if/then/fi` around OPs current examples:

```
$ if cd so_test_tmp; then cat nothing; cd ..; fi ; pwd
cat: nothing: No such file or directory
/tmp

$ if cd so_test_tmp; then cat something; cd ..; fi ; pwd
This is something
/tmp

$ if cd does_not_exist; then cat something; cd ..; fi ; pwd
-bash: cd: does_not_exist: No such file or directory
/tmp
```

Comment: Assuming that `cd ..` will succeed may _mostly_ be true, but why assume anything?

Comment: `(cd so_temp_test && exec cat nothing)` never has to run `cd ..`, so there's no possibility of it failing; and the subshell created by the parens is consumed by the `exec`, so there's no performance overhead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree with your comments, and I'd add a few more bits-n-pieces to the code to handle errors/issues (eg, verify directory/file exists before running `cd/cat`), but wanted to keep from going too far down a rabbit hole with 'add-ons' so I'm sticking with OP's original examples (I'm also assuming OP's 'real' problem is a bit more than some simple `cd/cat` calls)